# How many cores and what processors are used in the cloud ibmq_qasm_simulator?

Tags: ibm-q-experience, simulation

Cloud IBMQ simulator *ibmq_qasm_simulator* can process up to 32-qubit circuits quite fast. However, I could not find any information about the simulator backend properties, e.g. how many cores, what processors, etc.

**Could anybody provide me with this information (or link)?**